# Creating a jMeter Test Plan with less than 1 user per second

Tags: jmeter

I'm incredibly new to jMeter and am trying to create a test plan that will send 1000 users over the course of an hour. Originally I understood the ramp-up period to be how long it took all users to complete the task so I had:

```
Number of threads (users): 1000
Ramp-up Period (in seconds): 3600
Loop Count: 1
```

This however seems to be spinning up a lot more than what I need, which is basically one user pinging the server every 3.6 seconds.

What variable am I doing wrong? Is it possible to run a test this low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) . 
In your case you need to configure Target throutput to 16. And set Number of Threads value * Loop count = 1000. For example, 50 and 20.

Comment: Thanks Jay! I think Constant Throughput timer is exactly what I needed. Just to be clear, what would I set the ramp up period to in your example? Still leave it at 3600?

Comment: You don't need to set so big number. You can use ramp-up period to control how fast your test will reach maximum threads count. You can set just 5 or 10. It doesn't matter. 
Reed more here: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html